# Select rows in a data.frame when some rows repeat

Tags: r

I have the following toy dataset

```
set.seed(100)
df <- data.frame(ID = rep(1:5, each = 3),
                 value = sample(LETTERS, 15, replace = TRUE),
                 weight = rep(c(0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1), each = 3))
df

   ID value weight
1   1     I    0.1
2   1     G    0.1
3   1     O    0.1
4   2     B    0.1
5   2     M    0.1
6   2     M    0.1
7   3     V    0.5
8   3     J    0.5
9   3     O    0.5
10  4     E    0.2
11  4     Q    0.2
12  4     W    0.2
13  5     H    0.1
14  5     K    0.1
15  5     T    0.1
```

where each ID is an individual respondent, answering 3 questions (in the actual dataset, the number of questions answered is variable, so I can't rely on a certain number of rows per ID).

I want to create a new (larger) dataset which samples from the individual IDs based on the weights in `weight`.

```
probs <- data.frame(ID = unique(df$ID))
probs$prob <- NA
for(i in 1:nrow(probs)){
  probs$prob[i] <- df[df$ID %in% probs$ID[i],]$weight[1]
}
probs$prob <- probs$prob / sum(probs$prob)
sampledIDs <- sample(probs$ID, size = 10000, replace = TRUE, prob = probs$prob)
head(sampledIDs,10)

[1] 4 3 3 3 4 4 2 4 2 3
```

Moving from the probabilistic sampling of IDs to the actual creation of the new `data.frame` is stumping me.  I've tried

```
dfW <- df[df$ID %in% sampledIDs,]
```

but that obviously doesn't take into account the fact that IDs repeat.  I've also tried a loop:

```
dfW <- df[df$ID == sampledIDs[1],]
for(i in 2:length(sampledIDs)){
  dfW <- rbind(dfW, df[df$ID == sampledIDs[i],])
}
```

but that's *painfully* slow with a large dataset.

Any help would be very appreciated.

(Also, if there are simpler ways of doing the probabilistic selection of IDs, that would be great to hear too!)

Comment: Have you tried the package `sampling`?

Answer (score 1):

The code speed is low because you resize the data frame in every cycle of the `for` loop. Here is my suggestion. Create a dataframe with the final size that the data frame`dfW` will have before the `for` loop. Then assign the values from data frame `df` to `dfW` in the `for` loop. You may change the last part of your code with this:

```
dfW <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = 3 * length(sampledIDs), ncol = 3))
colnames(dfW) <- colnames(df)  # make the column names the same
for(i in 1:length(sampledIDs)){ # notice the start index is changed from 2 to 1
    #dfW <- rbind(dfW, df[df$ID == sampledIDs[i],])
    dfW[(3*i-2):(3*i),] <- df[df$ID == sampledIDs[i],]
}
```

Your code should run much faster with this change. Let me know how it goes!

Comment: The problem is, I don't know what the final size will be, since respondents in the real dataset answer anywhere from 1 to 10 questions.

Comment: I modified the previous solution and added a function that answer the concern when you don't know the final size of the dataframe. Hope this one will help. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the final size you can resize it whenever needed, but a new if condition should be added in the `for` loop. First define the function to resize the dataframe as follow:

```
double_rowsize <- function(df) {
  mdf <- as.data.frame(matrix(, nrow = nrow(df), ncol = ncol(df)))
  colnames(mdf) <- colnames(df)
  df <- rbind(df, mdf)
  return(df)
}
```

Then start the `dfW` with an initial size like 12 (3 times 4):

```
dfW <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = 12, ncol = 3))
colnames(dfW) <- colnames(df)
```

And finally add an `if` condition in the `for` loop to resize the dataframe whenever needed:

```
for(i in 1:length(sampledIDs)){ 
  if (3*i > nrow(dfW))
    dfW <- double_rowsize(dfW)
  dfW[(3*i-2):(3*i),] <- df[df$ID == sampledIDs[i],]
}
```

You can change the details of function double_rowsize to change the dataframe size with a different number rather than 2 if anything else works better. 2 is common because it works best in array resizing.

Good luck!